# Where are the implementations of the SdFat BlockDriver methods?

Tags: c++, library, sd

This is most probably more of a C++ question than an Arduino question; but since this is an Arduino library, I am asking here.

I am using the [SdFat](https://github.com/greiman/SdFat) library for my project. The library defines a `BlockDriver` object in one of its [header](https://github.com/greiman/SdFat/blob/master/src/BlockDriver.h) file which only declares the `typedef` of `BaseDriver` to some other classes.

```cpp
#if ENABLE_EXTENDED_TRANSFER_CLASS || ENABLE_SDIO_CLASS
typedef BaseBlockDriver BlockDriver;
#else  // ENABLE_EXTENDED_TRANSFER_CLASS || ENABLE_SDIO_CLASS
typedef SdSpiCard BlockDriver;
#endif  // ENABLE_EXTENDED_TRANSFER_CLASS || ENABLE_SDIO_CLASS
#endif // BlockDriver_h
```

`typedef SdSpiCard BlockDriver;` makes sense to me. But if `ENABLE_EXTENDED_TRANSFER_CLASS` or `ENABLE_SDIO_CLASS` are defined, `BlockDriver` is typedeffed into `BaseBlockDriver`. `BaseBlockDriver` is an abstract base class (as defined [here](https://github.com/greiman/SdFat/blob/master/src/FatLib/BaseBlockDriver.h)). An instance of the `BlockDriver` object is later used directly in the `FatVolume` class [here](https://github.com/greiman/SdFat/blob/635d3fd50f932a6dbac9a3d5baae97d1bdf2d0fc/src/FatLib/FatVolume.h#L270).

**My question is, how does `BlockDriver`'s method get defined when it abstract base class `BaseBlockDriver` is typedeffed to `BlockDriver`?**

Comment: did you read the answer?

Comment: I read it. It does not fully clarify it for me, so I am reluctant to accept it.

Comment: what is unclear in the answer?

Comment: I am not so good with programming which makes it difficult for me to understand. Basically I do not understand what "The typedef in BlockDriver.h is only for pointer type, not for instance of the object." means or implies. Even though we are declaring it as a pointer, we later call methods on it. How do those method work when `BlockDriver` is a `BaseBlockDriver`. Hope that clarified my confusion.

Comment: the SdSpiCard class should be derived from the BaseBlockDriver. but for AVR this consumed memory. so the author decided to leave out the base class for AVR. but then everywhere in the code where BaseBlockDriver was used as parameter type, an object of type SdSpiCard could not be used as value. He solved it with creating a macro BlockDriver which is BaseBlockDriver or SdSpiCard

Comment: I think I understand. Unfortunately, it is not clear for me yet on account of lack of understanding of OOP. I will accept your answer, but kindly elaborate on it and provide more background if you can find some time. Thanks for your patience and contribution.

Comment: there is nothing more. did you read my question to Bill Greiman and his answer on GitHub?

Comment: yes i did. Your answer does not explain the thing in detail and I believe can be improved. It takes for granted that the reader is well versed in OOP. 

I still do not get how one can call virtual methods. I.e. when `BlockDriver` is a `BaseBlockDriver` object, what are its actual methods? If my `BlockDriver` points to a `BaseBlockDriver` object (which in itself shouldnt be possible as that is an Abstract class), how do its methods get called. you tell me "The object is **always** of type SdSpiCard" whereas the typedef i quoted in my question clearly shows thats not the case.

Comment: if BaseBlockDriver class it not excluded, it is a base class for SdSpiCard. a pointer type to base class can point to an instance of a derived class. like you can refer to some Labrador as "a dog".

Comment: I think I now have some kind of understanding on this. Thank you for bearing with me. I will accept this answer. However, I still feel the answer could be much clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typedef in BlockDriver.h is only for pointer type, not for instance of the object. The object is always of type `SdSpiCard`, but in one case it is not an implementation of BlockDriverBase, so the function parameters can't refer it by base type.

```
#if ENABLE_EXTENDED_TRANSFER_CLASS || ENABLE_SDIO_CLASS
class SdSpiCard : public BaseBlockDriver {
#else  // ENABLE_EXTENDED_TRANSFER_CLASS || ENABLE_SDIO_CLASS
class SdSpiCard {
```

use of BlockDriver typedef

```
class FatFileSystem : public  FatVolume {
 public:
  bool begin(BlockDriver* blockDev, uint8_t part = 0) {
```

I was curious why the version without BaseBlockDriver. I asked the author Bill Greiman and he [answered](https://github.com/greiman/SdFat/issues/128):

> This is due to history. Long ago using a virtual base class cost lots
>   of RAM and flash so I did this mainly for 328 boards